# SQL Calculate 20 business days, remove bank hols and reference to another query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Sorry I am quite new to creating functions in SQL Server 2008 R2. I have largely been able to get by using T-SQL statements.

However I need to create a report that returns records with a date (program start date), that part is simple enough, however for each row date I want to calculate a target completion date based on 20 business days. I also want to avoid counting bank holidays too. I have a table named dCalendar which holds every day for the last few year with flags saying whether each day is a workday or bank holiday.

I have found lots of stuff on how to calculate the number of business days between two dates but this is more tricky.

I have created this function

```
ALTER function [warehouse].[MS_fnAddBusinessDays] 
    (@StartDate datetime,
     @nDays int) 
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
    RETURN 
        (SELECT calDt 
         FROM 
             (SELECT
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY calDt ASC) AS rownumber, 
                  calDt
              FROM 
                  warehouse.dCalendar
              WHERE 
                  (calDt >= @StartDate) 
                  AND (weekDayFg = 1) 
                  AND (BankHolidayFg = 0)) AS Results
    WHERE 
        (rownumber = @nDays)
```

and can call it using the following

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT  
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY calDt ASC) AS rownumber, 
         calDt, BankHolidayFg, weekDayFg, dateStr 
     FROM 
         warehouse.dCalendar 
     WHERE 
         (calDt >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-12-11 00:00:00', 102)) 
         AND (weekDayFg = 1) AND (BankHolidayFg = 0)) AS TblResults 
WHERE 
    (rownumber = 20)
```

I just cannot work out how to embed this within the following example where progStartDate is the date i want to calculate the target date from

```
SELECT     
    end_user.fContactVwDn.client_no, 
    end_user.fProgrammeVwDn.prtyProgrammeType, 
    end_user.fProgrammeVwDn.progStartDate, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN comtContactMeetingType = 'Visit' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS InitialVisitTotal, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN comtContactMeetingType = 'Visit' THEN contPlannedFromDate ELSE 0 END) AS InitialVisitDate
FROM
    end_user.fContactVwDn 
INNER JOIN
    warehouse.fContactProgramme ON end_user.fContactVwDn.contKy = warehouse.fContactProgramme.contKy 
INNER JOIN
    end_user.fProgrammeVwDn ON warehouse.fContactProgramme.progGuid = end_user.fProgrammeVwDn.progprogGuid
GROUP BY 
    end_user.fProgrammeVwDn.prtyProgrammeType, 
    end_user.fProgrammeVwDn.progStartDate, end_user.fContactVwDn.client_no
HAVING      
    (end_user.fProgrammeVwDn.prtyProgrammeType = 'Application') 
    AND (end_user.fProgrammeVwDn.progStartDate > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-07-01 00:00:00', 102))
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "and can call it using the following" <- I don't see where you call your function in the code snippet which follows this comment, looks like you have just copy/pasted the code from inside your function and specified a static value instead of the `@nDays` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The function looks OK. I would add `TOP`, though, to avoid scanning the whole `Calendar` table. I hope, `calDt` is a primary key.

```
ALTER function [warehouse].[MS_fnAddBusinessDays] 
    (@StartDate datetime,
    @nDays int) 
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN 
(
    SELECT calDt 
    FROM 
        (
            SELECT TOP(@nDays)
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY calDt ASC) AS rownumber, 
                calDt
            FROM 
                warehouse.dCalendar
            WHERE 
                (calDt >= @StartDate) 
                AND (weekDayFg = 1) 
                AND (BankHolidayFg = 0)
            ORDER BY calDt ASC
        ) AS Results
    WHERE 
        rownumber = @nDays
)
```

This function is inline table-valued function, which means that it returns a table, not a scalar value. This is good, because scalar functions usually make queries slow, but inline (single-statement) table-valued functions can be inlined by the optimiser.

To call such function use `CROSS APPLY`. It was originally introduced to SQL Server specifically for calling table-valued functions, but it can do [much more](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com.au/2011/04/t-sql-tuesday-017-it-slices-it-dices-it.html) (it is so called lateral join).

I wrapped your original query in a CTE to make the final query readable.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        end_user.fContactVwDn.client_no, 
        end_user.fProgrammeVwDn.prtyProgrammeType, 
        end_user.fProgrammeVwDn.progStartDate, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN comtContactMeetingType = 'Visit' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS InitialVisitTotal, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN comtContactMeetingType = 'Visit' THEN contPlannedFromDate ELSE 0 END) AS InitialVisitDate
    FROM
        end_user.fContactVwDn 
        INNER JOIN warehouse.fContactProgramme ON end_user.fContactVwDn.contKy = warehouse.fContactProgramme.contKy 
        INNER JOIN end_user.fProgrammeVwDn ON warehouse.fContactProgramme.progGuid = end_user.fProgrammeVwDn.progprogGuid
    GROUP BY 
        end_user.fProgrammeVwDn.prtyProgrammeType, 
        end_user.fProgrammeVwDn.progStartDate, 
        end_user.fContactVwDn.client_no
    HAVING      
        (end_user.fProgrammeVwDn.prtyProgrammeType = 'Application') 
        AND (end_user.fProgrammeVwDn.progStartDate > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-07-01 00:00:00', 102))
)
SELECT
    CTE.client_no, 
    CTE.prtyProgrammeType, 
    CTE.progStartDate, 
    CTE.InitialVisitTotal, 
    CTE.InitialVisitDate,
    F.calDt
FROM
    CTE
    CROSS APPLY [warehouse].[MS_fnAddBusinessDays](CTE.progStartDate, 20) AS F
;
```